# I use keras get a model file for .hdf5, how can covert it to .caffemodel?

Tags: keras, caffe, hdf5

I have used keras train a model,but I have to take  caffe to predict ,but I do not want to retrain the model,so I want to covert the .HDF5 file to .caffemodel

Answer (score 0):

nn_tools supports conversion from / to several NN frameworks, including from keras to caffe. It currently supports only conv and fc layers, but this is a good start: see [keras_to_caffe.py](https://github.com/hahnyuan/nn_tools/blob/master/keras_to_caffe.py).